# How to determine whether the mouse clicked on NSTextAttachment in NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nstextattachment

I understand that NSTextViewDelegate can complete click callbacks, but this does not meet our needs. We hope that an event will occur when the user presses the mouse and loosens his mouth.

```
textView(_:clickedOn:in:at:)
```

So we hope to start with NSTextView. I can judge press and release in mouseDown and mouseUp.

However, we only know how to get the corresponding coordinates. We don't know how to judge whether the mouse clicks in the NSTextAttachment or not. We also don't know how to judge which Attachment the user clicks.

How do I determine if a user clicks on an NSTextAttachment object when inheriting the mouseDown of NSTextView?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTextAttachment` is paired with a [`NSTextAttachmentCellProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextattachmentcellprotocol) object, which can receive messages tracking mouse events.

Comment: I know the tracking method, but I can only get the event under the mouse, there is no way to loosen the mouse.